# Trying to bring data with an input

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to populate some inputs depending by other inputs, but when i fill the first input thishow me an error of problems to connect with the data base

this is my HTML

```
     <!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>POC Ajax Cliente</title>

</head>
<body>
   <div id="cliente">
      <form action="" method="POST">
         <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
         <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" value="" placeholder="Nombre.." />
         <br />
         <label for="direccion">Dirección</label>
         <input type="text" id="direccion" name="direccion" value="" placeholder="Dirección.." />
         <br />
         <label for="telefono">Teléfono</label>
         <input type="text" id="telefono" name="telefono" value="" placeholder="Teléfono..." />
      </form>
   </div>
   <div id="estado">Esperando input.</div>
   <!-- Scripts -->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="cliente.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my client.js

```
$(function(){
   /* Ponemos evento blur a la escucha sobre id nombre en id cliente. */
   $('#cliente').on('blur','#nombre',function(){
      /* Obtenemos el valor del campo */
      var valor = this.value;
      /* Si la longitud del valor es mayor a 2 caracteres.. */
      if(valor.length>=3){

         /* Cambiamos el estado.. */
         $('#estado').html('Cargando datos de servidor...');

         /* Hacemos la consulta ajax */
         var consulta = $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'cliente.php',
            data:{nombre:valor},
            dataType:'JSON'
         });

         /* En caso de que se haya retornado bien.. */
         consulta.done(function(data){
            if(data.error!==undefined){
               $('#estado').html('Ha ocurrido un error: '+data.error);
               return false;
            } else {
               if(data.telefono!==undefined){$('#cliente #telefono').val(data.telefono);}
               if(data.direccion!==undefined){$('#cliente #direccion').val(data.direccion);}
               $('#estado').html('Datos cargados..');
               return true;
            }
         });

         /* Si la consulta ha fallado.. */
         consulta.fail(function(){
            $('#estado').html('Ha habido un error contactando el servidor.');
            return false;
         });

      } else {
         /* Mostrar error */
         $('#estado').html('El nombre tener una longitud mayor a 2 caracteres...');
         return false;
      }
   });
});
```

and this is my client.php where i make the consult from the DB

```
<?php

require 'config/Conexion.php';

if(!empty($_POST['nombre'])){

$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nombre = '.$nombre.'";  
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt ->execute();
$arrDatos = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


  if($arrDatos){
    foreach ($arrDatos as $row) {
      $return = array ('telefono' => $row['telefono'], 'direccion' => $row['direccion']);
    }
  } else {
    $return = array('error'=>'El nombre no esta guardado en la base de datos');
  }
  die(json_encode($return));
}
```

when i put something in the first input the message that apears is that there was a problem with the connection to the Data Base

Comment: What's a `birng` please? And a `thada`?

Comment: @MarkSetchell i'm sorry i didn't see, is bring